# iPad messaging problems

Tags: ios, ipad, messages, sms

I am trying to set up iMessage correctly, but I see no SMS / MMS options.
I do not see an option to use my phone number associated with the Apple ID.
Am I missing a simple step in the set up?

Answer (score 1):

To solve the first part of your question, [check this out](http://www.ianswerguy.com/sms-text-messages-on-an-ipad/):

> - On the iPhone, go to **Settings -> Messages -> Text Message Forwarding**.
>     This option will only appear when a compatible iOS or Mac device connected to the same Wi-Fi network.
> - Your iPad should be listed in the Text Message Forwarding setup window. Set the slider to the on position to enable text message forwarding to the iPad. Enable Text Forwarding
> - An authorization window should appear on the iPhone asking for a code.
> - The code is available in a window that will appear on your iPad.
> - Enter the code from the iPad into the authorization window on the iPhone. When the code is entered, this authorizes text messages to be forwarded to the iPad.
>     You will now be able to send and receive SMS text messages on the iPad.

From the [Apple Support Site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201349):

> #### If your phone number isn't listed on an iPod touch or iPad, follow
>   these steps:
>
> 1. [Update to the latest version of iOS](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4623).
> 2. Verify that you're using the same Apple ID that you're using on your iPhone.
> 3. On your iPad or iPod touch, sign out of your Apple ID in the following locations:
>
>    - Settings > Messages > Send & Receive. Tap your Apple ID, then tap Sign Out.
>    - Settings > FaceTime. Tap your Apple ID, then tap Sign Out.
> 4. Sign in to your Apple ID with FaceTime and iMessage.
>
> #### If your phone number still isn't listed, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Sign out of your Apple ID on all iOS devices, including your iPhone, in the following locations:
>
>    - **Settings > Messages > Send & Receive.** Tap your Apple ID, then tap Sign Out.
>    - **Settings > FaceTime. Tap your Apple ID**, then tap Sign Out.
> 2. Sign in to your Apple ID on your iPhone.
> 3. When activation is complete, your Apple ID and all verified email addresses should be visible in **Settings > Messages > Receive At and
>      Settings > FaceTime**.
> 4. Sign in to your Apple ID on your other iOS devices.